# When doing 'git submodule add...' how to get informations about the checkout versions both projects?

Tags: git

I have git-cloned a project from github and have git-submodule-added another one.
Doing git-describe in the root of the first one I get a proper information about the version. But doing a the same in the git-submodule-added one, it says: "fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything".
How can I get informations about the current version of both properly?
When I got updates via git-pull later how can I ensure to get updated informations of the current version of what is on my harddisc about both then?

Comment: Does the submodule project have any annotated tags? Describe will by default only show these.

Comment: Ok...that is the reason! :)
git describe cannot report anything, when there is nothing.
Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git describe` only shows annotated tags, if you don't have any it can't show them.

But you could also try `git describe --tags` to show all tags or `git describe --all` to even use branches.